# mongodb - Find count of values in other collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I want to find how many "taskId" of below collectionOne is present in collectionTwo.
Here, "taskId" in below collectionOne is embedded inside a array in a document.

Also, Let me know the different approaches to do this (if possible).

```
db.collectionOne.find({"sId":"DCNrnPeKFrBv" }).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "sX8o7mJhebs",
        "sId" : "DCNrnPeKFrBv",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "oId" : "7SycYQ",
                        "taskId" : 146108906
                },
                {
                        "oId" : "7SycYQ",
                        "taskId" : 14623846
                },
                {
                        "oId" : "fANQ",
                        "taskId" : 1461982
                },
                {
                        "oId" : "fAeNQ",
                        "taskId" : 131732
                },
                {
                        "oId" : "t6AF5yn",
                        "taskId" : 197681
                }
        ]
}



> db.collectionTwo.find().pretty().limit(2)
{
        "_id" : 146108906,
        "oId" : "7SycYQ",
        "name" : "ABC"
}
{
        "_id" : 1461982,
        "oId" : "fANQ",
        "name" : "XYZ"
}
```

In collectionTwo "_id" is equivalent to  "taskId" of collectionOne.

Comment: Added sample documents of collectionTwo.  In collectionTwo "_id" is equivalent to "taskId" of collectionOne.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator to do a left join on `collectionTwo`, you can get the counts as follows:

```
db.collectionOne.aggregate([
    { $match: { sId: "DCNrnPeKFrBv" }},
    { $lookup: {
        from: "collectionTwo",
        localField: "data.taskId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "tasksCount"
    } },
    { $addFields: { 
        tasksCount: { $size: "$tasksCount" }
    } }
])
```

or if using older MongoDB server versions (below 3.2):

```
db.collectionOne.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$data" },
    { $lookup: {
        from: "collectionTwo",
        localField: "data.taskId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "tasks"
    } },
    { $unwind: "$tasks" },
    { $group: {
        _id: "$tasks._id",
        count: { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { $group: {
        _id: null,
        tasksCount: { "$sum": "$count" }
    } }
])
```

---

--**EDIT**--

An alternative is to get a list of all the distinct taskIds in collectionOne, and use that list as count query on collectionTwo e.g.

```
var taskIds = db.collectionOne.distinct("data.taskId");
var tasksCount = db.collectionTwo.count({ "_id": { "$in": taskIds } });
printjson(taskIds);
printjson(tasksCount);
```

Comment: Can we change its output to {"count" : 2}  -- Just the count , instead of two documents as output.  { "_id" : 1461982, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 146108906, "count" : 1 }

Comment: Hi, I need total count of all taskIds present in collectionOne. (This is the requirement). In above scenario it is two, so i need output as  {"count" : 2}

Comment: Typo on above comment. My Bad.  I need total count of all taskIds present in collectionTwo. (This is the requirement). In above scenario it is only two taskIds of collectionOne is present in collectionTwo, so i need output as {"count" : 2}

Comment: Yes, the new answer is fine. Can you please give me a solution for MongoDB version below 3.2.

Comment: @user3802384 Updated with an alternative

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks a lot for the solution & quick responce. :)